# Lower bound $\log^\tau (k+1) - \log^\tau k$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I'm having trouble in finding non-zero lower bound of:

$\log^\tau{(k+1)} - \log^\tau{k}$

for any $\tau \in \mathbb{R}: \tau>0$ with large enough $N\in \Bbb R$, $\forall$ $2\le k \le N$.

Comment: $0$ is certainly a lower bound. What kind of lower bound do you want exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose first $\tau\ge1$. If $0<a<b$ then, by the mean value theorem
$$
b^\tau-a^\tau=\tau\,c^{\tau-1}\,(b-a),\quad a<c<b.
$$
Since $\tau-1\ge0$ we have
$$
b^\tau-a^\tau>\tau\,a^{\tau-1}\,(b-a).
$$
Then
$$
\log^\tau{(k+1)} - \log^\tau{k}\ge\tau\,(\log^{\tau-1}k)\log\Bigl(1+\frac1k\Bigr).
$$

If $0<\tau<1$ then $\tau-1<0$ and then
$$
b^\tau-a^\tau=\tau\,c^{\tau-1}\,(b-a)>\tau\,b^{\tau-1}\,(b-a)
$$
and
$$
\log^\tau{(k+1)} - \log^\tau{k}\ge\tau\,(\log^{\tau-1}(k+1))\log\Bigl(1+\frac1k\Bigr).
$$

Comment: I'm very sorry. I mislead you in my definitions. There is $2\le k \le N$ instead of $2 \le \tau \le N$.

Comment: The same idea works. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I don't think this expression works (or it's not absolutely clear that it works) for any large $N$:
$\log^\tau{(k+1)} - \log^\tau{k}\ge\tau\,(\log^{\tau-1}(N+1))\log\Bigl(1+\frac1N\Bigr)$
$\forall 2\le k \le N$.

Comment: $\log(1+1/k)\ge\log(1+1/N)$ holds for $2\le k\le N$. If $0<\tau<1$, then $\tau-1<0$ and $\log^{\tau-1}(k+1)\ge\log^{\tau-1}(N+1)$. If $\tau\ge1$, then $\log^{\tau-1}k\ge\log^{\tau-1}2$.

Comment: So. if I understand correctly, when $\tau\ge1$:

$\log^\tau{(k+1)} - \log^\tau{k}\ge\tau\,(\log^{\tau-1}(2))\log\Bigl(1+\frac1N\Bigr)\forall k:2\le k\le N$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.